# Cannot remotely access PostgreSQL on EC2 instance

Tags: postgresql, configuration, aws, remote

I was unable to access a remote AWS postgres database via things
like `psql -h *EC2ExternalIP* -U *me*`.  I would get:

```
psql -h *EC2ExternalIP* -U *me*
psql: could not connect to server: Operation timed out
Is the server running on host *EC2ExternalIP* and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

same thing trying a simple telnet connection to this port:

```
curl telnet://*EC2ExternalIP*:5434
curl: (7) Failed to connect to *EC2ExternalIP* port 5434:
Operation timed out
```

and even though i could access other services (eg, apache) on this
same *EC2ExternalIP*.

So I poked around at threads like these:

- [How to connect to an remote PostgreSQL database on Ubuntu using pgAdmin3?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18717/how-to-connect-to-an-remote-postgresql-database-on-ubuntu-using-pgadmin3)
- [Connect to remote EC2 Postgresql database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91585/connect-to-remote-ec2-postgresql-database?rq=1)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/423165/remotely-access-postgresql-database/827358#827358
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770329/cannot-connect-to-postgresql-remotely-on-amazon-ec2-instance-using-pgadmin

and they helped me to ensure I'd made appropriate modifications to
`postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf`; the right settings for you will
depend on your instance's security concerns.  But it is still not
working.

**What should I do to make this DB accessible?**

Answer (score 4):

(self-answering in case someone else has these same symptoms!)

Then I stumbled upond [Shubham Dipt's](https://www.shubhamdipt.com/) post on
["PostgreSQL on EC2 (Ubuntu) in AWS"](https://www.shubhamdipt.com/blog/postgresql-on-ec2-ubuntu-in-aws/),
making me aware of the "Security group" layer AWS maintains.  It's
easy to specify a new one  via the AWS console, specifically adding  `Custom TCP: 5432, Source: Anywhere` and `SSH TCP:22, Source: Anywhere` rules for Inbound:

[image: EC2 console editing Security group]

Then, added this security group to the instance, and it worked for me.

Comment: FYI terrible idea to open this up if you use password security for production. Use AWS VPC or if you just need to admin use a keypair and SSH to the EC2 instance instead.

Comment: @mattdlockyer TOTALLY CORRECT!!  this was from a year ago, and i've learned a lot about AWS since.  i've un-checked my self-answer, but for anyone else stumbling by this way, use VPC's!!